# Move the picture top to bottom

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I move a picture from top to bottom and then get it in other coordinates?

I will explain my problem more clearly: I want the image to start at the top right corner of the form and go down, then appear in the middle of the top and go down again.

I wrote the code, but it just goes down and I don't know how to proceed.

```
 private int x = 5;
 private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
          
            pictureBox1.Top += x;
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(350,0);
                x += 5;
            Invalidate();
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you incrementing x by 10 once you hit the bottom?

Comment: Top + x is wrong.  X is the width and Y is the height.  It should be Top +y or Left + x.  the with goes positive left to right.  The height goes positive going down (not up).

Comment: @RaulF oh sorry it was misspelled
but anyway I don't achieve the desired result :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be what you're looking for. Basically you need to start on top, then slowly move to bottom. When you touch the bottom, go back to the middle of the container and go down once more. This code does not place the picture on the right but you should be able to do it yourself if you understand what the code does ;)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer timer;
    private const int dtY = 5;
    private bool resetOnce;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, 0, 50);
    }

    private void Callback(object state)
    {
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, pictureBox1.Location.Y + dtY);

            // when it touches the bottom of the container
            if (pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Size.Height > pictureBox1.Parent.Height) 
            {
                // we already reset once, so no more going back up: stop the timer
                if (resetOnce)
                {
                    timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
                // we did not reset yet, so go to middle of container
                else
                {
                    resetOnce = true;
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, pictureBox1.Parent.Height / 2 - pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only 1 error, it is timeout error (Error CS0103 The name 'Timeout' does not exist in the current context), i think i can fix it, thanks.

Comment: This class is in the `System.Threading` namespace, you need to import that. Sorry, I did not include the `using` section.